# typesafe.config - external config file is not working

Tags: java, command-line, typesafe-config

I have **application.conf** file on my classpath, included in the jar:

```
{    
  db.class : "org.h2.Driver"
  db.url : "jdbc:h2:~/database.db"
  db.username : sa
  db.password : ""
}
```

And I want my app to use external .conf file, which is /home/user/cfg/app.conf:

```
{    
  db.class : "org.h2.Driver"
  db.url : "jdbc:h2:~/prod.db"
  db.username : someusername
  db.password : somepassword
}
```

I launch my app with -Dconfig.file option:

```
java -Dconfig.file="/home/user/cfg/app.conf" -jar application.jar
```

But ConfigFactory.load() still loads **application.conf** from classpath, ignoring the external file.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you happen to read through the Standard behavior of typesafe config at [Standard behavior](https://github.com/lightbend/config#standard-behavior) ?

Perhaps you could try their suggestion.

It says "These system properties specify a replacement for application.{conf,json,properties}, not an addition. They only affect apps using the default ConfigFactory.load() configuration. In the replacement config file, you can use include "application" to include the original default config file; after the include statement you could go on to override certain settings."